# Read data from node inside a node Realm iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, realm

I'm pretty new to Realm and I'm trying to integrate Realm with Firebase. I'm fetching data using realm using a predicate.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isArchived == NO AND userId == %@", [User userId]];
RLMResults *dbrecents = [[Recent objectsWithPredicate:predicate] sortedResultsUsingProperty:FRECENT_LASTMESSAGEDATE ascending:NO];
```

and my firebase data structure,

[image: Firebase structure]

my `Recent` object has the exact same values like in firebase structure,

```
@property NSString *objectId;
@property NSString *userId;
@property NSString *groupId;
@property NSString *initials;
@property NSString *picture;
@property NSString *description;
@property NSString *members;
@property NSString *password;
@property NSString *type;
@property NSString *fullname;
@property NSString *senderName;
@property NSInteger counter;
@property NSString *lastMessage;
@property NSTimeInterval lastMessageDate;
@property BOOL isArchived;
@property BOOL isDeleted;
@property BOOL message_me;
@property NSTimeInterval createdAt;
@property NSTimeInterval updatedAt;
```

When I'm retrieving data, the `dbrecents` is empty. How may I fix this?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without more information. It might be that you haven't added any objects matching that predicate to your Realm. Could you please share the result of logging `RLMResults *dbrecents = [[Recent allObjects] sortedResultsUsingProperty:FRECENT_LASTMESSAGEDATE ascending:NO];
`? Thanks!

Comment: it's empty result set..

Comment: Then you have no data. To add data to Realm, see Realm's docs on writes: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#writes